# NodeJS 'jquery' npm package not working($.on())

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I have `jquery` installed and loaded `$ = require('jquery');`

But when I try to use it:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
    $.on('ready', function () {

    }
}
```

It throws me a `TypeError: $.on is not a function`

I was told to use 'jQuery', but 'jQuery' is deprecated and it tells me to use 'jquery'

Edit: also depercated jQuery package doesn't even load correctly

Comment: What's $.on supposed to do in this case?

Comment: It's right there in the error, `$.on` is not a function.

Comment: Try not using jQuery on the server.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to load the jQuery package on the page directly and allow it to be used on NodeJS.

This is an example done with JADE and EXPRESS.

First you load the jQuery package `script(src='/js/jQuery.js')` then you render your index where you have you jQuery package `res.render('index');` and now you can use jQuery on NodeJS

**DON'T FORGET**
instead of using `document` `window` you have to use `response.window` `response.document`